# Bayesian Networks Implementation with Example

Tags: bayesian

I am trying to Code a Bayesian Network in .NET. I found a library called Infer.Net by Microsoft Research which is used for Probabilistic Reasoning about the Networks. But it would be easier if I could find a simple Example implementing a Bayesian Network using Infer.Net. I searched and unable to couldn't find one. Can some one point me out with the exemplified implementation of Bayesian Net in .Net or using Infer.Net.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a .NET implementation of bayesian networks, but I'm using SMILE for my research (http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/). It's a C++ library but they provide a .NET wrapper. It's pretty well documented so it should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple Bayesian network [example](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/Discrete%20Bayesian%20network.aspx) included with Infer.NET.  The code is at (your install folder)/Samples/C#/ExamplesBrowser/WetGrassSprinklerRain.cs.